# loop ActiveX checkboxes with a variable

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a number of ActiveX checkboxes in a Word document that are called 'CheckBox1', 'CheckBox2' etc.

I have a private sub for a when a button is clicked it looks at these checkboxes and if certain boxes are ticked it runs a macro. If I access the checkboxes individually using me.CheckBox1, me.CheckBox2 etc the code works fine, but I want to be able to run a loop that runs through them like me.checkBox[variable] but I can't get it to work. Any ideas? Thanks!

Follow-up:
I have tried the code that Tim kindly put below however I am still unable to use the checkboxes in a meaningful way. I have put in:

```vb
Sub checkCheckBox()

    Dim obj, i As Long
    Dim boxName As String
    
    For i = 1 To 10
        Set obj = GetControlByName(ThisDocument, "CheckBox" & i)
        boxName = obj.Name
        If ThisDocument.boxName.Value = True Then
            .... ' do something
        End If
        
    Next i

End Sub
```

If I use ThisDocument.CheckBox1.Value and hard code it that way it works, but it is not liking the variable.

Comment: If you have existing code then it's always a good idea to include it in your post.

Comment: Thanks. The existing code that works is If Me.CheckBox1.Value = True Then .... but if I try and do If Me.CheckBox[iCount].Value or Me.CheckBox&iCount.Value or anything like that it doesn't work (where iCount is a declared integer variable)

Comment: If you need to check the value of a checkbox you get back from `GetControlByName` then you can just use (eg in your code above) `obj.Value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no direct method, but you can make a function to find a control by name:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim obj, i As Long
    
    For i = 1 to 10
        Set obj = GetControlByName(ThisDocument, "CheckBox" & i)
        Debug.Print obj.Name 'do something with the checkbox...
    Next i

End Sub


Function GetControlByName(doc As Document, nm As String) As Object
    Dim obj, rv As Object
    For Each obj In doc.InlineShapes
        If Not obj.OLEFormat Is Nothing Then
            If obj.OLEFormat.Object.Name = nm Then
                Set GetControlByName = obj.OLEFormat.Object
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next obj
End Function
```

Comment: This is great and allows me to loop through the checkboxes however I still can't seem to use them in any way. What I would like to do is: If me.obj.name.Value = True then ... but I am still getting an error "method or data member not found".

Comment: If you have a follow-up question about what I posted, you can edit your question to add it there (along with any code you're having a problem with)

Comment: Just `If obj.Value Then`